# Mixing dichotomous and polytomous items in one test

Tags: item-response-theory

I have to evaluate a test paper which contains both dichotomous and polytomous items. I am currently using R. But in R IRT models for scoring of dichotomous and polytomous items are different and I have not found any way of combining both type of items so how can I mix both dichotomous and polytomous items into one. Specifically -

1. Is there any programme/function in R that handles both dichotomous and polytomous items
2. If no direct function can combine both dichotomous and polytomous items in R then is there any indirect way of doing it
3. If not 1 and 2 then any other open source IRT software which can handle dichotomous and polytomous items together

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there are several: **eRm**, **mirt**, **ltm** etc. In fact, most IRT models can handle dichotomous items as a special case of polytomous items. E.g. in ltm, you can use grm on polytomous and dichotomous items:

```
R> library(ltm)
R> data(Science)
R> summary(Science)
```

We see the Science data are polytomous (4-levels). Let's first fit the graded response model to the original items

```
R> mpol<-grm(Science[c(1,3,4,7)])
R> summary(mpol)Call:
R> grm(data = Science[c(1, 3, 4, 7)])

Model Summary:
   log.Lik      AIC      BIC
 -1608.871 3249.742 3313.282

Coefficients:
$Comfort
         value
Extrmt1 -4.672
Extrmt2 -2.536
Extrmt3  1.408
Dscrmn   1.041

$Work
         value
Extrmt1 -2.385
Extrmt2 -0.735
Extrmt3  1.849
Dscrmn   1.226

$Future
         value
Extrmt1 -2.281
Extrmt2 -0.965
Extrmt3  0.856
Dscrmn   2.299

$Benefit
         value
Extrmt1 -3.060
Extrmt2 -0.906
Extrmt3  1.543
Dscrmn   1.094


Integration:
method: Gauss-Hermite
quadrature points: 21 

Optimization:
Convergence: 0 
max(|grad|): 0.0092 
quasi-Newton: BFGS
```

Now I will dichotomize the first item, Comfort, like so

```
R> Science2<-Science
R> levels(Science2$Comfort)<-c("negative","negative","positive","positive")
R> summary(Science2)
```

We see now that the first item has levels "strongly disagree" and "disagree" combined into "negative" and "strongly agree" and "agree" combined into "positive".

```
R> mmixed<-grm(Science2[c(1,3,4,7)])
R> summary(mmixed)

Call:
grm(data = Science2[c(1, 3, 4, 7)])

Model Summary:
   log.Lik      AIC      BIC
 -1411.065 2850.129 2905.727

Coefficients:
$Comfort
         value
Extrmt1 -3.261
Dscrmn   0.762

$Work
         value
Extrmt1 -2.455
Extrmt2 -0.750
Extrmt3  1.900
Dscrmn   1.176

$Future
         value
Extrmt1 -2.076
Extrmt2 -0.887
Extrmt3  0.787
Dscrmn   3.086

$Benefit
         value
Extrmt1 -3.468
Extrmt2 -1.020
Extrmt3  1.737
Dscrmn   0.927


Integration:
method: Gauss-Hermite
quadrature points: 21 

Optimization:
Convergence: 0 
max(|grad|): 0.057 
quasi-Newton: BFGS
```

So, you see, this is possible for all packages that support polytomous items. See sections 2.1. to 2.4. in [this review on IRT packages in R](http://epub.wu.ac.at/4010/1/resrepIRThandbook.pdf).

Comment: While it's true the dichotomous 2PL model is actually a special case of the graded response model (which is what is shown here) OP may be asking about mixing different classes of items, like modelling a 3PL model while also modelling graded models for some polytomous responses and perhaps a nominal model for others if the order is not known a priori. Not as many R packages do that, and of the packages you mentioned, only `mirt` can do this with the `itemtype` input to specify the respective item types.

Comment: This is a good point. Perhaps the OP can clarify this in his question. Also, kernSmoothIRT should be able to do this iirc.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys. As Momo suggested I will clarify the requirement further with an example - So I have a test consisting of 10 items. 7 of them are MCQ which can be scored with 0 (incorrect) and 1 (correct). But the rest 3 items are essay type questions and possible scores are - 0.0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75 and 1.0. Now I want to evaluate score of each student on this test using IRT. So what should be my approach.

Comment: Thanks, @Deepak. In this case, I think my answer should work for you: The 7 MCQ are to be used as binary items and the other 3 are Rating Scale or Partial Credit Item. Depending on the dimensionality of the items, ltm and mirt should be your friend for IRT and eRm for Rasch models.

Comment: I'm still a bit hesitant about this. For MCQ's there is a baseline probability of simply guessing correctly, which is what the 3PL model is for (whether the lower bound is estimated or not is another story, sometimes it's better just to set it as 1/#choices). I think the 2PL is really only justifiable in personality inventories, or in ability questions where guessing is likely not present (like a fill in the blank type-question).